# Ruby on Rails + PostgreSQL app fails to start on AWS EC2. Error is: "cannot load such file -- pg_ext (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems, amazon-web-services, pg

I began by installing all these dependencies:

```
sudo yum install ruby19 ruby19-devel gem rubygems19-devel make gcc postgresql9 postgresql9-devel postgresql9-server
```

Then I switch to the root user and I run

```
bundle install
```

and I get the green success message:

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

However, when I cd to the dir and run

```
rails s -p80
```

it I get all this and it fails to start (I'm still root because bind won't work to port 80 if I'm not root):

```
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg_ext (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/user/TransForm/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Perhaps there is an easy way to just deploy it correctly from the begining instead of messing around with error craps?  I need PostgreSQL.  This app works everywhere except this AWS EC2 instance, so I know my Gemfile is correct.  Any clues would help.

Comment: I've got almost the exact same problem.  :(

Answer (score 1):

open `irb` & type `require "pg"` does it work? if not, then check that `pg_ext` exists in `/usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/` directory.   you can install manually postgresql gem manually, using

```
gem install pg
```

If this still doesn't work, ensure that you are using latest version of ruby & latest version of rubygems using `gem environment` command.if its the older version, you can install latest ones using [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)

Answer (score 0):

```
        use gem pg 
            than 
             bundle install
             bundle update
               please not use any version of pg 
       I face this error and solved by this
```

Comment: I assume that this is a valid answer. Try to rephrase and reformat it to make it more understandable.